# How to get this symbol (looks like a T or J)

Tags: symbols

I've tried drawing this symbol in [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), but with no luck:

[image: T pic]

It's not `\mathcal{TJ}`: $\mathcal{TJ}$ or `\mathscr{TJ}`: $\mathscr{TJ}$.

I'm guessing it's a T from context in the textbook.  It has the same height as a capital letter.

How do I produce this symbol in mathjax (where I'm writing my textbook notes) and $\LaTeX$?

Comment: Try \mathcal{T} or \mathscr{T}

Comment: @Johannes_B Nope: see updated question for what they give.

Comment: I think this is a stylized tau of some sort

Comment: Btw.: Do you know about http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html ? It's really helpful for these kind of things...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)

Comment: If you found this symbol in a PDF file you can also look up the properties of the document to see which fonts are being used. This might help you to narrow your search to symbols from these specific fonts.

Comment: Don't you recognise this? It looks like the Greek "tau" letter.

Answer (score 13):

The symbol is a scipt uppercase T in math mode. The package `euscript` should fit your needs.
Try

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{T}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

to obtain

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another very minimal example to obtain your symbol is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eucal}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathcal{T} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, this is a calligraphic T in Euler script font. This font can also be loaded with the wonderful package [`mathalpha`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha), which gives an easy way to use many calligraphic, script, fraktur and blackboard bold math fonts.

The Euler script font is associated to the `\mathcal` alphabet when loading `mathalpha` with option `cal=euler`. Here's a complete example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=euler]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathcal{T} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]